# Getting RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tree, networkx

Trying to plot a hierarchical tree-like structure but getting error when branches are leading to a common output.

Got no error while plotting the hierarchical tree with distinct outputs but error is occurring when the outputs are common.

```
def Create_Hierarchy(chunks):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(chunks)
    pos = _hierarchy_pos(G, root='A', width=0.07, vert_gap=0.02, vert_loc=0.09, xcenter=0.50)    
    nx.draw(G, pos, arrows=True, with_labels=True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, wspace=4.0, hspace=2.99)
    plt.savefig('D:\\Hierarchy'+timestr+'.png')
    plt.show()
    # return rootTree
print(Create_Hierarchy(chunks=[('A','B'), ('A','C'), ('A','D'), ('A','E'), ('A','F'), (**'B','G'**), (**'C','G'**), ('D','I'), ('E','J'), ('F','K')]))
```

Errors:

```
  File "D:\Selenium Workspace\PyDemoProject\src\Tree.py", line 67, in _hierarchy_pos
    pos = _hierarchy_pos(G, child, width=dx, vert_gap=vert_gap, vert_loc=vert_loc-vert_gap, xcenter=nextx, pos=pos, parent=root)
  File "D:\Selenium Workspace\PyDemoProject\src\Tree.py", line 67, in _hierarchy_pos
    pos = _hierarchy_pos(G, child, width=dx, vert_gap=vert_gap, vert_loc=vert_loc-vert_gap, xcenter=nextx, pos=pos, parent=root)
  File "D:\Selenium Workspace\PyDemoProject\src\Tree.py", line 67, in _hierarchy_pos
    pos = _hierarchy_pos(G, child, width=dx, vert_gap=vert_gap, vert_loc=vert_loc-vert_gap, xcenter=nextx, pos=pos, parent=root)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "D:\Selenium Workspace\PyDemoProject\src\Tree.py", line 59, in _hierarchy_pos
    children = list(G.neighbors(root))
  File "C:\Users\VG-11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 1266, in neighbors
    return iter(self._adj[n])
```

Comment: Well the problem might be that when you have a child `G` with more parents `B, C`, you no longer have a hierarchy/tree. It's a directed acyclic graph now, but not hierarchy anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Modified the code as:

def Create_Hierarchy(chunks):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from(chunks)

It is working as expected now.

Comment: Good. :) Plese write it as an answer and mark it as such. In case someone searches for this problem.